Issue in inserting data in a table
I have made a table:
CREATE TABLE Dept (
  Dcode number(2) primary key,
  Dname varchar2(20) unique check (Dname in ('Acc', 'Resea', 'Ope', 'Exe')),
  Floor varchar2(2)Not null
);

Insert command:
INSERT INTO Dept VALUES (13,'Exe','G');

When I am trying to enter data in it it shows the following message
Error starting at line : 21 in command -
INSERT INTO Dept VALUES (13,'Exe','G')
Error report -
ORA-00001: unique constraint (WAJID.SYS_C007019) violated

what should I do?
I have tried to enter data in the table in sql developer but it showing error.

In general, rather than relying on system generated constraint names (such as SYS_C007019), you should name your constraints so that you know which one is failing:
CREATE TABLE Dept (
  Dcode NUMBER(2)
        CONSTRAINT Dept__Dcode__PK primary key, 
  Dname VARCHAR2(20)
        CONSTRAINT Dept__Dname__U unique
        CONSTRAINT Dept__Dname__CHK check (Dname in ('Acc', 'Resea', 'Ope', 'Exe')),
  Floor VARCHAR2(2)
        NOT NULL
);

Note: You can choose your own naming convention but it is helpful to be able to unambiguously identify the table, column(s) and, sometimes, constraint type.
Then when you run your insert:
INSERT INTO Dept (Dcode, Dname, Floor) VALUES (13, 'Exe', 'G');

You should see an error that looks something like:
Error report - ORA-00001: unique constraint (WAJID.DEPT__DNAME__U) violated

Then you know that the error comes from the unique constraint on the dname column of the dept table.
Once you know that then you know that there is already a row in the dept table that has a department name of Exe and you are trying to insert a second department with that name.

If having two departments with the same name is correct then having a UNIQUE on the column is wrong and you should remove the constraint. Once you've done that then you can INSERT as many duplicate names as you want (assuming the other constraints are validated).
If you should not have two departments with the same name then:

It is correct that the INSERT failed and the database has done the correct thing by raising an exception; and

Maybe what you intended is to UPDATE the existing row rather than trying to create a new row:
UPDATE Dept
SET   Dcode = 13, Floor = 'G'
WHERE Dname = 'Exe';






If you just want to know which constraint is failing (without explicitly renaming the constraints) then you can use:
SELECT *
FROM   user_constraints
WHERE  table_name = 'DEPT'
AND    constraint_name = 'SYS_C007019';

and the constraint_type column will tell you if it is the primary P or unique U constraint that has been violated.
or:
SELECT *
FROM   user_cons_columns
WHERE  table_name = 'DEPT'
AND    constraint_name = 'SYS_C007019';

Which will tell you the column name that the constraint validates.

The error message doesn't specify which column the WAJID.SYS_C007019 constraint refers to, but it means your insert statement is violating the expected uniqueness. I.e., already have an entry in the table with either the same dcode or the same dname value (or both). Use different values and you should be fine.
